# XUL iframe firefox addon, how to change the src within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a firefox addon,

in my settings page `dialog.xul` i have an iframe where i load different settings pages `page1.xul` `page2.xul` `page3.xul`

***Iframe :***

```
<vbox flex="1">
  <iframe
      id="iframe"
      src="chrome://xxx/content/page1.xul"
      flex="1"></iframe>
</vbox>
```

***Within the iframe*** i need to navigate from `page2.xul` to `page3.xul`
with the code in page2.xul

***My code (page2.xul) :***

```
gBrowser.loadURI("chrome://xxx/content/page3.xul");
```

Also tried

```
 document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("src", "chrome://xxx/content/page3.xul");
```

but it's not working i know iframe container is not accessible from the iframe but how can i do that redirection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iframe in XUL you must create it with the HTML namespace otherwise things like load events don't work right, see this topic: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2809781&hilit=+iframe

Once you do that, changing src etc should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks bro for the info i did not know about it

Comment: no it did not ... i ended implementing it in the main javascript code

Comment: we must be careful html name space disabled many propriety like centerscreen when window.open is called, also width, height ans screenX... etc was ignored... i don't recommend adding html namespace on xul (i did not need them but i thought it was good idea to add them at the end it was not lol)

Comment: Thanks very much for that knowledge share intika I didnt know that, but it totally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution :***

I managed to handle the code in the main XUL

Apparently XUL does not support the structure

```
[XUL1 >> iframe(XUL2 : change something in XUL1)]
```

This structure is not supported in classic `HTML + Javascript` for security reason 
and it's also the case in XUL

Comment: Did using namespace fix it up?

Comment: That's weird I regulary change the src of iframe. For instance i do it in this gist here: https://gist.github.com/yajd/9085804

Comment: i was doing something wrong for sure i think it's related to controlling the iframe within the page in the iframe... but any way i just putted my code some where else in the js file (no more in the xul file) and it's okay but thanks for the advice ;)